# Send Ctrl or Alt + key in AutoHotkey to multiple windows (dualbox)

Tags: autohotkey, alt, ctrl, multibox

I have an AutoHotkey script that can send same keystrokes to multiple windows and it works well.

But I need to also send Ctrl or Alt + Key.

To simplify, I need this: when I push "2", I need to send to both windows "Alt+2"

now my script is like this:

```
~2::
KeyWait 2
IfWinActive, World of Warcraft
{
  ControlSend,, 2, ahk_id %wowid1%
  ControlSend,, 2, ahk_id %wowid2%
  Return
}
```

I tried with

```
  ControlSend,, {Alt}2, ahk_id %wowid2%
```

and with

```
  ControlSend,, {Ctrl}2, ahk_id %wowid2%
```

but it doesn't work

then I tried this:

```
ControlSend,, !2, ahk_id %wowid1%
ControlSend,, !2, ahk_id %wowid2%
```

and

```
ControlSend,, ^2, ahk_id %wowid1%
ControlSend,, ^2, ahk_id %wowid2%
```

and it sends "Alt + 2" or "Ctrl + 2" but only to the current window.

The other windows do not get the keystroke

Comment: This looks like World of Warcraft. I know that many games seem to ignore AHK. Have you been able to send AHK keyboard strings to an active window using Send? If that doesn't work, then you have to investigate what you need to do to send to WoW in the first place. E.g. play with Send options or try to send Virtual key or Scan code data.

Comment: The simple script works in World of Warcraft, so the game does not ignore AutoHotkey. I tried to send strings like "london" and "england" to the WoW windowses and it works. But it doesn't work sending Alt+2. I think the problem is that it releases "Alt" it before pressing "2"

Comment: So, sending ControlSend,, London, ahk_id %wowid1% and ControlSend,, England, ahk_id %wowid2% works?

Comment: yes it worls. I open chat with my WoW characters and it types "london" and "england"

Comment: Have you tried: ControlSend,, {Alt Down}2{Alt Up}, ahk_id %wowid2%?

Comment: I tried it now and it works! thanks! (sorry for late answer)